# What is best way to update domain class object with large number of variables

Tags: grails, groovy, constructor

Suppose I have Employee domain class, I want to create object of domain class from params map coming from UI side.

I can create object in two ways as follows

1. Normal way

> Employee employee = new Employee(name: params.name, rollNo:
>   params.rollNo)

and so on. If domain class has 20 variables, then we need to write all variables in above constructor.

2. Following is best way to create object

> Employee employee = new Employee(params)

Above constructor will populate object with matching params. Right.

Now my question comes here.

If suppose I have existing domain class object fetched from DB, Now I want to update this object from params map coming from UI.
What is best way to do this (like we do in above second option).

Comment: I wouldn't set lots of fields at the same time.  Someone could manipulate their post message, an update fields which aren't on the form for them to fill in.  this would be very hard to spot, find and fix.  just set the fields like normal.  though if you've got 20 things on a page, I'd argue that's too many...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best to use command objects and bind it to the Employee.

here is sample pseudo code:

```
class EmployeeMgmtController {
    def editEmp(EmployeeCmd cmd){
        Employee editEmp = Employee.get(1)
        editEmp.properties = cmd
        editEmp.save()
    }
}

class EmployeeCmd{
    String id

    static constraints = {
        id blank:false,nullable:false
    }
}
```

or,

you if your on controller, and still want to use params (and exclude any fields that you don't want to bind):

```
bindData(editEmp, params, [exclude:['firstName', 'lastName']])
```

Comment: You do not answer his question. He's asking about updating, not creating object.

Comment: Almost the same.. Thx for spotting that. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve that in a service class, make your service implement `grails.web.databinding.DataBinder` then use the `bindData` method as demonstrated below.

```
import grails.web.databinding.DataBinder

class MyAwesomeService implements DataBinder {

    /**
    * Updates the given instance of a domain class to have attribute values specified
    * in "newData" map.
    */
    MyDomain updateMyDomainAttributes(MyDomain myDomianInstance, Map newData) {
        bindData(myDomianInstance, newData)
        myDomianInstance.save(flush: true)
    }
}
```